# r- how do I to create confusion matrix from my dataset

Tags: r

Can anyone advise me and help me to create a confusion Matrix for the SVM model because I am getting the following error:

```
"Error: 'data' and 'reference' should be factors with the same levels."
```

from the Confusion Matrix code below...

```
confusionMatrix(predA, tmp_test$Score)
```

I also tried

```
confusionMatrix(table(predA, tmp_test))
```

I then got the following error...

```
"Error in table(predA, tmp_test) : all arguments must have the same length"
```

SVM model is regression.

sample table...

```
Unhelpful Score 
7     1
8     3
5     1
7     2
4     1 
4     1
5     1
9     2
6     1
5     1
11    3
```

There are 2108 obs and 2 variables. There are no missing or invalid data or 0 (zero) values. Unhelpful value ranges from 4 to 2016. Score value ranges from 1 to 3.

Here is my my code...

```
# Random sampling
samplesize = 0.60 * nrow(dsTemp)
set.seed(80)
index = sample(seq_len(nrow(dsTemp)), size = samplesize)

# Create training and test set
datatrain = dsTemp[ index, ]
datatest = dsTemp[ -index, ]


library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(tidyverse)

tmp_train <-datatrain
tmp_test <- datatest

#orginally datatypes were int but I had to change to factor for the model 
#to work
dsTemp$Score <- factor(dsTemp$Score)
dsTemp$Unhelpful <- factor(dsTemp$Unhelpful)

dsTemp$Unhelpful <- factor(dsTemp$Unhelpful)
dsTemp$Score <- factor(dsTemp$Score)

#svm model
Model <- svm(Score ~., data=tmp_train,kernel='linear',gamma=0.2,cost=100)

#predictions
predA <- predict(svmModel, tmp_test)
```

**EDIT**

```
tmp_train$Score <- factor(tmp_train$Score)
tmp_test$Score <- factor(tmp_test$Score)

tmp_train$HelpfulnessDenominator <- factor(tmp_train$HelpfulnessDenominator)
tmp_test$HelpfulnessDenominator <- factor(tmp_test$HelpfulnessDenominator)
```

Getting error after

```
confusionMatrix(predA, tmp_test)
```

or

```
confusionMatrix(table(predA, tmp_test))  

str(predA)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1264] "927" "1179" "1655" "156" …

str(tmp_test$Score)
Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 3 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not changing to `factors` in both train and test set, but instead in `dsTemp`:

```
dsTemp$Score <- factor(dsTemp$Score)
dsTemp$Unhelpful <- factor(dsTemp$Unhelpful)

dsTemp$Unhelpful <- factor(dsTemp$Unhelpful)
dsTemp$Score <- factor(dsTemp$Score) #also this is just a repetition
```

Instead it should probably be:

```
tmp_train$Score <- factor(tmp_train$Score)
tmp_test$Score <- factor(tmp_test$Score)
```

Because these are the datasets that you're calling later:

```
#svm model
Model <- svm(Score ~., data=tmp_train,kernel='linear',gamma=0.2,cost=100)

#predictions
predA <- predict(svmModel, tmp_test)
```

And this is the correct call for `confusionMatrix`:

```
confusionMatrix(predA, tmp_test$Score)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I am receiving error "all arguments must have the same length" where you suggested correction?

Comment: After which line?

Comment: line on - confusionMatrix(predA, tmp_test$Score)

Comment: can you show here `str(predA)` and `str(tmp_test$Score)`?

Comment: Have a look at the top

Comment: and they have the same `length()`?

Comment: yes - .i.e - length(unique(sapply(tmp_train, length))) == 1 or length(unique(sapply(tmp_train$Score, length))) == 1. before I created train test set I also did...dsTemp <- filter(dsTemp, Unhelpful >3, Score <=3)

Comment: I have created a new script and for some reason or the other (probably I had other models in the same script), confusion matrix for svm was created. with the aid from RLave, thanks RLave